# Counting words and word stems in a large dataframe (RStudio)

Tags: r, dictionary, text, text-mining, stringr

I have a large dataframe consisting of tweets, and a keyword dictionary loaded as a list that has words and word stems associated with emotion (`kw_Emo`). **I need to find a way to count how many times any given word/word stem from `kw_Emo` is present each tweet.** In `kw_Emo`, word stems are marked with an asterisk ( * ). For example, one word stem is `ador*`, meaning that I need to account for the presence of `adorable`, `adore`, `adoring`, or any pattern of letters that *starts* with `ador…`.

---

From a previous Stack Overflow discussion (see previous question on my profile), I was greatly helped with the following solution, but it only counts exact character matches (Ex. only `ador`, not `adorable`):

1. Load relevant package.

   `library(stringr)`
2. Identify and remove the `*` from word stems in `kw_Emo`.

   `for (x in 1:length(kw_Emo)) {
     if (grepl("[*]", kw_Emo[x]) == TRUE) {
       kw_Emo[x] <- substr(kw_Emo[x],1,nchar(kw_Emo[x])-1)
         }`
       }
3. Create new columns, one for each word/word stem from `kw_Emo`, with default value 0.

   `for (x in 1:length(keywords)) {
     dataframe[, keywords[x]] <- 0}`
4. Split each Tweet to a vector of words, see if the keyword is equal to any, add +1 to the appropriate word/word stems' column.

   `for (x in 1:nrow(dataframe)) {
     partials <- data.frame(str_split(dataframe[x,2], " "), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     partials <- partials[partials[] != ""]
     for(y in 1:length(partials)) {
       for (z in 1:length(keywords)) {
         if (keywords[z] == partials[y]) {
           dataframe[x, keywords[z]] <- dataframe[x, keywords[z]] + 1
         }
       }
     }
   }`

Is there a way to alter this solution to account for word stems? I'm wondering if it's possible to first use a stringr pattern to replace occurrences of a word stem with the exact characters, and then use this exact match solution. For instance, something like `stringr::str_replace_all(x, "ador[a-z]+", "ador")`. But I'm unsure how to do this with my large dictionary and numerous word stems. Maybe the loop removing `[*]`, which essentially identifies all word stems, can be adapted somehow?

---

Here is a reproducible sample of my dataframe, called `TestTweets` with the text to be analysed in a column called `clean_text`:

`dput(droplevels(head(TestTweets, 20)))`

```
structure(list(Time = c("24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:03", "24/06/2016 10:55:03"
), clean_text = c("mayagoodfellow as always making sense of it all for us ive never felt less welcome in this country brexit  httpstcoiai5xa9ywv", 
"never underestimate power of stupid people in a democracy brexit", 
"a quick guide to brexit and beyond after britain votes to quit eu httpstcos1xkzrumvg httpstcocniutojkt0", 
"this selfinflicted wound will be his legacy cameron falls on sword after brexit euref httpstcoegph3qonbj httpstcohbyhxodeda", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"this is a very good summary no biasspinagenda of the legal ramifications of the leave result brexit httpstcolobtyo48ng", 
"you cant make this up cornwall votes out immediately pleads to keep eu cash this was never a rehearsal httpstco", 
"no matter the outcome brexit polls demonstrate how quickly half of any population can be convinced to vote against itself q", 
"i wouldnt mind so much but the result is based on a pack of lies and unaccountable promises democracy didnt win brexit pro", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"absolutely brilliant poll on brexit by yougov httpstcoepevg1moaw", 
"retweeted mikhail golub golub\r\n\r\nbrexit to be followed by grexit departugal italeave fruckoff czechout httpstcoavkpfesddz", 
"think the brexit campaign relies on the same sort of logic that drpepper does whats the worst that can happen thingsthatarewellbrexit", 
"am baffled by nigel farages claim that brexit is a victory for real people as if the 47 voting remain are fucking smu", 
"not one of the uks problems has been solved by brexit vote migration inequality the uks centurylong decline as", 
"scotland should never leave eu  calls for new independence vote grow httpstcorudiyvthia brexit", 
"the most articulate take on brexit is actually this ft reader comment today httpstco98b4dwsrtv", 
"65 million refugees half of them are children  maybe instead of fighting each other we should be working hand in hand ", 
"im laughing at people who voted for brexit but are complaining about the exchange rate affecting their holiday\r\nremain", 
"life is too short to wear boring shoes  brexit")), .Names = c("Time", 
"clean_text"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here is `kw_Emo`:

`kw_Emo <- c("abusi*", "accept", "accepta*", "accepted", 
        "accepting", "accepts", "ache*", "aching", "active*", "admir*", 
        "ador*", "advantag*", "adventur*", "advers*", "affection*", "afraid", 
        "aggravat*", "aggress*", "agoniz*", "agony", "agree", "agreeab*", 
        "agreed", "agreeing", "agreement*", "agrees", "alarm*", "alone", 
        "alright*", "amaz*", "amor*", "amus*", "anger*", "angr*", "anguish*", 
        "annoy*", "antagoni*", "anxi*", "aok", "apath*", "appall*", "appreciat*", 
        "apprehens*", "argh*", "argu*", "arrogan*", "asham*", "assault*", 
        "asshole*", "assur*", "attachment*", "attract*", "aversi*", "avoid*", 
        "award*", "awesome", "awful", "awkward*", "bashful*", "bastard*", 
        "battl*", "beaten", "beaut*", "beloved", "benefic*", "benevolen*", 
        "benign*", "best", "better", "bitch*", "bitter*", "blam*", "bless*", 
        "bold*", "bonus*", "bore*", "boring", "bother*", "brave*", "bright*", 
        "brillian*", "broke", "burden*", "calm*", "cared", "carefree", 
        "careful*", "careless*", "cares", "casual", "casually", "certain*", 
        "challeng*", "champ*", "charit*", "charm*", "cheer*", "cherish*", 
        "chuckl*", "clever*", "comed*", "comfort*", "commitment*", "complain*", 
        "compliment*", "concerned", "confidence", "confident", "confidently", 
        "confront*", "confus*", "considerate", "contempt*", "contented*", 
        "contentment", "contradic*", "convinc*", "cool", "courag*", "crap", 
        "crappy", "craz*", "create*", "creati*", "credit*", "cried", 
        "cries", "critical", "critici*", "crude*", "cry", "crying", "cunt*", 
        "cut", "cute*", "cutie*", "cynic", "danger*", "daring", "darlin*", 
        "daze*", "dear*", "decay*", "defeat*", "defect*", "definite", 
        "definitely", "degrad*", "delectabl*", "delicate*", "delicious*", 
        "deligh*", "depress*", "depriv*", "despair*", "desperat*", "despis*", 
        "destruct*", "determina*", "determined", "devastat*", "difficult*", 
        "digni*", "disadvantage*", "disagree*", "disappoint*", "disaster*", 
        "discomfort*", "discourag*", "dishearten*", "disillusion*", "dislike", 
        "disliked", "dislikes", "disliking", "dismay*", "dissatisf*", 
        "distract*", "distraught", "distress*", "distrust*", "disturb*", 
        "divin*", "domina*", "doom*", "dork*", "doubt*", "dread*", "dull*", 
        "dumb*", "dump*", "dwell*", "dynam*", "eager*", "ease*", "easie*", 
        "easily", "easiness", "easing", "easy*", "ecsta*", "efficien*", 
        "egotis*", "elegan*", "embarrass*", "emotion", "emotional", "empt*", 
        "encourag*", "energ*", "engag*", "enjoy*", "enrag*", "entertain*", 
        "enthus*", "envie*", "envious", "excel*", "excit*", "excruciat*", 
        "exhaust*", "fab", "fabulous*", "fail*", "fake", "fantastic*", 
        "fatal*", "fatigu*", "favor*", "favour*", "fear", "feared", "fearful*", 
        "fearing", "fearless*", "fears", "feroc*", "festiv*", "feud*", 
        "fiery", "fiesta*", "fine", "fired", "flatter*", "flawless*", 
        "flexib*", "flirt*", "flunk*", "foe*", "fond", "fondly", "fondness", 
        "fool*", "forgave", "forgiv*", "fought", "frantic*", "freak*", 
        "free", "freeb*", "freed*", "freeing", "freely", "freeness", 
        "freer", "frees*", "friend*", "fright*", "frustrat*", "fuck", 
        "fucked*", "fucker*", "fuckin*", "fucks", "fume*", "fuming", 
        "fun", "funn*", "furious*", "fury", "geek*", "genero*", "gentle", 
        "gentler", "gentlest", "gently", "giggl*", "giver*", "giving", 
        "glad", "gladly", "glamor*", "glamour*", "gloom*", "glori*", 
        "glory", "goddam*", "gorgeous*", "gossip*", "grace", "graced", 
        "graceful*", "graces", "graci*", "grand", "grande*", "gratef*", 
        "grati*", "grave*", "great", "grief", "griev*", "grim*", "grin", 
        "grinn*", "grins", "grouch*", "grr*", "guilt*", "ha", "haha*", 
        "handsom*", "happi*", "happy", "harass*", "hated", "hateful*", 
        "hater*", "hates", "hating", "hatred", "hazy", "heartbreak*", 
        "heartbroke*", "heartfelt", "heartless*", "heartwarm*", "heh*", 
        "hellish", "helper*", "helpful*", "helping", "helpless*", "helps", 
        "hesita*", "hilarious", "hoho*", "homesick*", "honour*", "hope", 
        "hoped", "hopeful", "hopefully", "hopefulness", "hopeless*", 
        "hopes", "hoping", "horr*", "hostil*", "hug", "hugg*", "hugs", 
        "humiliat*", "humor*", "humour*", "hurra*", "idiot", "ignor*", 
        "impatien*", "impersonal", "impolite*", "importan*", "impress*", 
        "improve*", "improving", "inadequa*", "incentive*", "indecis*", 
        "ineffect*", "inferior*", "inhib*", "innocen*", "insecur*", "insincer*", 
        "inspir*", "insult*", "intell*", "interest*", "interrup*", "intimidat*", 
        "invigor*", "irrational*", "irrita*", "isolat*", "jaded", "jealous*", 
        "jerk", "jerked", "jerks", "joke*", "joking", "joll*", "joy*", 
        "keen*", "kidding", "kind", "kindly", "kindn*", "kiss*", "laidback", 
        "lame*", "laugh*", "lazie*", "lazy", "liabilit*", "libert*", 
        "lied", "lies", "like", "likeab*", "liked", "likes", "liking", 
        "livel*", "LMAO", "LOL", "lone*", "longing*", "lose", "loser*", 
        "loses", "losing", "loss*", "lost", "lous*", "love", "loved", 
        "lovely", "lover*", "loves", "loving*", "low*", "luck", "lucked", 
        "lucki*", "luckless*", "lucks", "lucky", "ludicrous*", "lying", 
        "mad", "maddening", "madder", "maddest", "madly", "magnific*", 
        "maniac*", "masochis*", "melanchol*", "merit*", "merr*", "mess", 
        "messy", "miser*", "miss", "missed", "misses", "missing", "mistak*", 
        "mock", "mocked", "mocker*", "mocking", "mocks", "molest*", "mooch*", 
        "mood", "moodi*", "moods", "moody", "moron*", "mourn*", "nag*", 
        "nast*", "neat*", "needy", "neglect*", "nerd*", "nervous*", "neurotic*", 
        "nice*", "numb*", "nurtur*", "obnoxious*", "obsess*", "offence*", 
        "offens*", "ok", "okay", "okays", "oks", "openminded*", "openness", 
        "opportun*", "optimal*", "optimi*", "original", "outgoing", "outrag*", 
        "overwhelm*", "pained", "painf*", "paining", "painl*", "pains", 
        "palatabl*", "panic*", "paradise", "paranoi*", "partie*", "party*", 
        "passion*", "pathetic*", "peculiar*", "perfect*", "personal", 
        "perver*", "pessimis*", "petrif*", "pettie*", "petty*", "phobi*", 
        "piss*", "piti*", "pity*", "play", "played", "playful*", "playing", 
        "plays", "pleasant*", "please*", "pleasing", "pleasur*", "poison*", 
        "popular*", "positiv*", "prais*", "precious*", "pressur*", "prettie*", 
        "pretty", "prick*", "pride", "privileg*", "prize*", "problem*", 
        "profit*", "promis*", "protested", "protesting", "proud*", "puk*", 
        "radian*", "rage*", "raging", "rancid*", "rape*", "raping", "rapist*", 
        "readiness", "ready", "reassur*", "reek*", "regret*", "reject*", 
        "relax*", "relief", "reliev*", "reluctan*", "remorse*", "repress*", 
        "resent*", "resign*", "resolv*", "restless*", "revigor*", "reward*", 
        "rich*", "ridicul*", "rigid*", "risk*", "ROFL", "romanc*", "romantic*", 
        "rotten", "rude*", "sad", "sadde*", "sadly", "sadness", "sarcas*", 
        "satisf*", "savage*", "scare*", "scaring", "scary", "sceptic*", 
        "scream*", "screw*", "selfish*", "sentimental*", "serious", "seriously", 
        "seriousness", "severe*", "shake*", "shaki*", "shaky", "share", 
        "shared", "shares", "sharing", "shit*", "shock*", "shook", "shy*", 
        "sigh", "sighed", "sighing", "sighs", "silli*", "silly", "sincer*", 
        "skeptic*", "smart*", "smil*", "smother*", "smug*", "snob*", 
        "sob", "sobbed", "sobbing", "sobs", "sociab*", "solemn*", "sorrow*", 
        "sorry", "soulmate*", "special", "splend*", "stammer*", "stank", 
        "startl*", "stink*", "strain*", "strange", "strength*", "stress*", 
        "strong*", "struggl*", "stubborn*", "stunk", "stunned", "stuns", 
        "stupid*", "stutter*", "succeed*", "success*", "suck", "sucked", 
        "sucker*", "sucks", "sucky", "sunnier", "sunniest", "sunny", 
        "sunshin*", "super", "superior*", "support", "supported", "supporter*", 
        "supporting", "supportive*", "supports", "suprem*", "sure*", 
        "surpris*", "suspicio*", "sweet", "sweetheart*", "sweetie*", 
        "sweetly", "sweetness*", "sweets", "talent*", "tantrum*", "tears", 
        "teas*", "tehe", "temper", "tempers", "tender*", "tense*", "tensing", 
        "tension*", "terribl*", "terrific*", "terrified", "terrifies", 
        "terrify", "terrifying", "terror*", "thank", "thanked", "thankf*", 
        "thanks", "thief", "thieve*", "thoughtful*", "threat*", "thrill*", 
        "ticked", "timid*", "toleran*", "tortur*", "tough*", "traged*", 
        "tragic*", "tranquil*", "trauma*", "treasur*", "treat", "trembl*", 
        "trick*", "trite", "triumph*", "trivi*", "troubl*", "TRUE", "trueness", 
        "truer", "truest", "truly", "trust*", "truth*", "turmoil", "ugh", 
        "ugl*", "unattractive", "uncertain*", "uncomfortabl*", "uncontrol*", 
        "uneas*", "unfortunate*", "unfriendly", "ungrateful*", "unhapp*", 
        "unimportant", "unimpress*", "unkind", "unlov*", "unpleasant", 
        "unprotected", "unsavo*", "unsuccessful*", "unsure*", "unwelcom*", 
        "upset*", "uptight*", "useful*", "useless*", "vain", "valuabl*", 
        "valuing", "vanity", "vicious*", "vigor*", "vigour*", "villain*", 
        "violat*", "virtuo*", "vital*", "vulnerab*", "vulture*", "warfare*", 
        "warm*", "warred", "weak*", "wealth*", "weapon*", "weep*", "weird*", 
        "welcom*", "well*", "wept", "whine*", "whining", "willing", "wimp*", 
        "win", "winn*", "wins", "wisdom", "wise*", "witch", "woe*", "won", 
        "wonderf*", "worr*", "worse*", "worship*", "worst", "wow*", "yay", 
        "yays","yearn*","stench*")`

---

Code used from MRau's answer that hasn't worked for me:

```
ind_stem <- grep("[*]", kw_Emo)
kw_stem  <- gsub("[*]", "", kw_Emo[ind_stem])
kw_word  <- kw_Emo[-ind_stem]
tweets <- strsplit(TestTweets[, "clean_text"], "\\s+")

for (kws in kw_stem) {
  count_i <- unlist(lapply(tweets, function(x) length(grep(kws, x))))
  TestTweets <- cbind(TestTweets, count_i)
  colnames(TestTweets)[ncol(TestTweets)] <- paste0(kws, "*")
}
for (kww in kw_word) {
  count_i <- unlist(lapply(tweets, function(x) length(grep(paste0("^", kww, "$"), x))))
  TestTweets <- cbind(TestTweets, count_i)
  colnames(TestTweets)[ncol(TestTweets)] <- kww
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all I would get rid of some of the `for` loops:

```
ind_stem <- grep("[*]", kw_Emo)
kw_stem  <- gsub("[*]", "", kw_Emo[ind_stem])
kw_word  <- kw_Emo[-ind_stem]
tweets <- strsplit(TestTweets[, "clean_text"], "\\s+")
```

I generated a different vector for words and stems. `tweets` is a list of vector of words - `strsplit` splits the strings using blank space (`\\s+`) as separator.

When it comes to the matching of words/stems, you can use `grep` for both. By default, it will find all the words containing the given pattern:

```
> grep("Abc", c("Abc", "Abcdef"))
[1] 1 2
```

But you can get the "exact" match if you use `^` and `$`:

```
> grep("^Abc$", c("Abc", "Abcdef"))
[1] 1
```

In you code, you want to look at the length of the `grep` output and e.g. append it to your `data.frame`:

```
for (kws in kw_stem) {
    count_i <- unlist(lapply(tweets, function(x) length(grep(kws, x))))
    TestTweets <- cbind(TestTweets, count_i)
    colnames(TestTweets)[ncol(TestTweets)] <- paste0(kws, "*")
}
for (kww in kw_word) {
    count_i <- unlist(lapply(tweets, function(x) length(grep(paste0("^", kww, "$"), x))))
    TestTweets <- cbind(TestTweets, count_i)
    colnames(TestTweets)[ncol(TestTweets)] <- kww
}
```

Fragment of output:

```
> TestTweets[19:20, c("clean_text", "boring")]
                                                                                                                    clean_text boring
19 im laughing at people who voted for brexit but are complaining about the exchange rate affecting their holiday\r\nremain      0
20                                                                           life is too short to wear boring shoes  brexit      1
```

Of course, you can further optimize this code or decide whether or not use `grep(paste0("^", kws), x)` instead of `grep(kws, x)` in the first loop depending on your problem etc.

Comment: Can you explain how to consolidate your answer into a usable code? I have tried using it and been unsuccessful. Including the first part where you make new vectors for words and stems, which has resulting in empty values. [I have added the code I used from your answer in the original post]

Comment: @JasonB can you describe what exactly is not working (post error message if any, check where do NAs appear)? Take into account that I use the exact variables from your post, so e.g. my TestTweets has no levels.

Comment: For instance, `ind_stem` is saved in my environment as "integer (empty)", `kw_stem` and `kw_word` are "character (empty)", and `kws` and `kww` are "NULL (empty)". Maybe there is something wrong with my `grep`? The rest of the code doesn't do anything since it relies on this first step.

Comment: @JasonB Are you using the original `kw_Emo` vector (the one you posted)? Seems to me that you try to run `grep("[*]", kw_Emo)` after already substracting "*" from it in step 2 of your code.

Comment: good point, completely my fault. Now I've got `ind_stem`, `kw_stem`, and `kw_word` loaded correctly. But I'm getting an error with the `tweets` value: `tweets <- strsplit(TestTweets[, "clean_text"], "\\s+")` 
`Error in strsplit(TestTweets[, "clean_text"], "\\s+") : 
  non-character argument`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I've changed edited the `tweets` code to be `tweets <- strsplit(TestTweets$clean_text, " ")`, which I think will effectively do the same thing?

Comment: @JasonB again, check with the table you posted ;) I copied it and assigned to TestTweets. Your original table probably has factors, not characters.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've just noticed that that word stems are being counted if they're present anywhere in a word, as a result of the `grep` function (Ex. `ador*` is counted as it appears in words like `matador`). Is there anyway to edit the code to only pick up word stems when they're at the beginning of a word, as a true stem (Ex. `ador` should only be counted in `adore`, `adorable`, `adoring`, etc... but NOT in words like `matador`)?

Comment: @JasonB use `grep(paste0("^", kws), x)` instead of `grep(kws, x)` in the first loop